# Programa para detectar buena sintaxis en una operación aritmética básica

Tags: python

Por que mi programa en python 3 para detectar buena sintaxis en una operación aritmética básica me retorna False?
He escrito un programa en python 3 que busca errores de sintaxis dentro de una operación aritmética basica de forma muy reducida, aclaro que solo es en sintaxis, realmente no comprueba si esta bien desarrollado, es decir,
si tengo

```
2+3=4 -> True
```

Retorna True a pesar de ser una mala suma, ya que solo comprueba la sintaxis,
contraejemplo

```
2++4=5 -> False
```

habiendo aclarado esto expongo el código

```
def sintaxis(entrada):
    if entrada[-1] in simbolos: #El final no debe ser un simbolo
        return False
    if entrada.isdigit(): #Si la entrada es solo un numero de N digitos tambien es falso
        return False
    #Recorre el string y compara cada caracter con el anterior caracter del string, si ambos son un simbolo entonces retorna false
    caracter_anterior = ""
    for caracter in entrada:
        if caracter in simbolos and caracter_anterior in simbolos:
            return False
        caracter_anterior = caracter
    return True
    
simbolos = "+-=<>"
entrada = "3+8=2"

if sintaxis(entrada):
    print("Tiene buena sintaxis")
else:
    print("No tiene buena sintaxis")
```

Bien, mi duda es que no logro comprender bien el porque si modifico la variable `entrada` a `entrada="+8"` ingresa a

```
for caracter in entrada:
        if caracter in simbolos and caracter_anterior in simbolos:
            return False
        caracter_anterior = caracter
```

y devuelve False, acaso la variable `caracter_anterior = ""` influye en ese recorrido?, si lo es asi no logro entender bien, espero puedan ayudarme a comprender, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La condición correcta es:

```
if not entrada.isdigit():  # Si la entrada es solo un numero de N digitos tambien es falso
    return False
```

Te faltó el `not`.

Tal como está en el original:

```
if entrada.isdigit():  # Si la entrada es solo un numero de N digitos tambien es falso
    return False
```

la función retorna si el primer caracter es un dígito, y sigue adelante si no lo es.